# Boxes filled with mysql data when clicked lead to new pages

Tags: php, mysql

I have created boxes/threads that feed off of data from a mysql data page.  I was wondering how I could make it so when I clicked on the box it would take me to a page that keep all of the same info in the box.  I would preferably like to have this done in a method that would read a column in the data base and not just the box so I can later have comments attacked to each thread. Any help at all would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$selection = "ORDER BY  id ASC";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$selection=isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : ""; 
if($selection == "1"){$selection="ORDER BY id DESC";}       // if selection equals to 1 then sort by newest
else if($selection == "2"){$selection="ORDER BY id ASC";}   // else if selection equals to 2 then sort by oldest


$sql="SELECT id, threadName, message FROM threads ";        // don't forget space the end of sql
$sql.=$selection;

mysql_select_db('threads');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $id = $row['id'];
  $threadName = $row['threadName'];
  $message = $row['message'];
  echo "<div class='boxed'><center>".$threadName."<br>".$message."</center></div>";
} 
?>
```

This is the code that fetches the code from the mysql database and puts it inside of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Add to div onclick event and when click run js function that open neede page

```
<?

echo '<div onclick="f(\''.$threadName.'\');return false;" class=\'boxed\'><center>'.$threadName.'<br>'.$message.'</center></div>';

<script>
function f('threadName'){
document.location="/nedded_page.php?open_inp="+threadName; //set your url 
}
</script>
?>
```

or add a link `<a href="/open_page?p='.$threadName.'">`

```
echo '<div class=\'boxed\'><a href="/open_page?p='.$threadName.'"><center>'.$threadName.'<br>'.$message.'</center></a></div>';
```